# Добрый день, сделал на Open Server оправку писем через SMTP (gmail) зарегистрировал бесплатный хостинг, но отправка не происходит?

Tags: php, telegram, бот, smtp

подскажите, с сделал на Open Server оправку писем через SMTP (gmail) зарегистрировал бесплатный хостинг, но отправка не происходит, так же само и телеграмм бота, с опен сервера отправляет, а с хостинга бесплатного нет!?

Comment: Не ломай голову и отправляй почту через PHPMailer

Comment: я так и делаю же

Comment: А дебаг включить на хостинге? Плюс - может это ограничения самого бесплатного хостинга?

Comment: дибаг всмысле настройки на самом хостинге или же с помощь функции?

Comment: Функций которые можно написать самостоятельно. И настроек error_reporting() и ini_set()

Comment: перепроверьте настройки smtp на сервере; проверьте спам и оповещения в ящике ЖиМэйл

Comment: Бесплатный хостинг вам ничем не обязан)